# Jenkins Groovy: Update the labels in all nodes

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a few hundred jenkins nodes and need to update the labels in all of them.

It seems the easiest would be to run a groovy script in the Jenkins master script console that would add the extra label to each node's config.

Question: How would one do this in groovy?

Comment: Add labels meeting condition :  https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Add+a+new+label+to+slaves+meeting+a+condition

Comment: Thanks, that worked. You should add it as an answer so I can mark it as one.